# Python list of numpy matrices behaving strangely

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, numpy

I am trying to work with lists of numpy matrices and am encountering an annoying problem.

Let's say I start with a list of ten 2x2 zero matrices

```
para=[numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros((2,2)))]*(10)
```

I access individual matrices like this

```
para[0]
para[1]
```

and so on. So far so good.

Now, I want to modify the first row of the second matrix only, leaving all the others unchanged. So I do this

```
para[1][0]=numpy.matrix([[1,1]])
```

The first index points to the second matrix in the list and the second index points to the first row in that matrix, replacing it with [1,1].

But strangely enough, this command changes the first row of ALL ten matrices in the list to [1,1] instead of just the second one like I wanted. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you multiply the initial list by 10, you end up with a list of 10 numpy arrays which are in fact references to the the same underlying structure. Modifying one will modify all of them because in fact there's only one numpy array, not 10.

If you need proof, check out this example in the REPL:

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros(10)
>>> a = [numpy.zeros(10)]*10
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True
>>>
```

The `is` operator checks if both objects are in fact the same(not if they are equal in value).

What you should do is use a list comprehension to generate your initial arrays instead of a multiplication, like so:

```
para=[numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros((2,2))) for i in range(10)]
```

That will call `numpy.matrix()` ten times instead of just once and generate 10 distinct matrixes.

Comment: Alternatively, if you the number of matrices is fixed (e.g. 10), write `para = numpy.zeros((10, 2, 2))`. Then the assignment would look like: `para[0,1,:] = numpy.matrix([1, 1])`.

Comment: Right, I answered this in the most general way possible and not numpy-specific because this will happen if you multiply any list that contains mutable objects. Not just numpy arrays.